# default route with linkdown

Tags: linux, routing, route, iproute

If no link on enp0s18 i have

```
root@route:~# ip r
default via a.a.a.1 dev enp0s18 metric 10 linkdown 
default via a.a.b.1 dev enp0s10 metric 20 onlink linkdown 
default via x.x.x.49 dev wwx001e101f0000 metric 30
```

Expected that default swiches to x.x.x.49, but it tries `linkdown` route

```
root@route:~# ping -n ya.ru
PING ya.ru (87.250.250.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
From a.a.a.231 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From a.a.a.231 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From a.a.a.231 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
```

Link state

```
4: enp0s10: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:af:f7:08:27:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp0s18: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:d3:14:83:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Result: Traffic black-holed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In new kernel we have new defaults. Solution is

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enp0s10/ignore_routes_with_linkdown
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enp0s18/ignore_routes_with_linkdown
```

And make new default

```
echo net.ipv4.conf.all.ignore_routes_with_linkdown=1 > /etc/sysctl.d/10-linkdown.conf
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/10-linkdown.conf
```

Comment: Why have you not accepted your own answer? It does work...

Comment: @AJSmith'Smugger' because there is 2 day timeout before I can accept my own answer. I switched to another tasks and forget it:)

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue of "inactive linkdown"

And I do not have `/etc/sysctl.d/10-linkdown.conf` file in my development board.

So I tried with the solution "`echo 1 > /proc/...../ignore_routes_with_linkdown`"

and next checking ip route show gives "dead inactive linkdown".

Any comments/suggestions?

Comment: Create this file. If you have no /etc/sysctl.d/ dir - append this "net.ipv4.conf.all.ignore_routes_with_linkdown=1" to /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: But there is no /etc/sysctl.conf as well

Comment: create it. look to dmesg to check